# How to insert row when finding a match in a column?

Tags: excel, match, vba

Hopefully my issue described below is a simple one.  I am still very new to VBA and can't seem to get past my current wall...good and bad days with respect to learning.  Unfortunately this week has me at a loss for how to move on.

The macro shown below will is essentially run on a spreadsheet with 2 sheets (MPL & CAD).

- MPL sheet = simple table of information
- CAD sheet contains 3 tables of varying width (i.e. the first table spans from column C to AE, the 2nd and 3rd tables span from column C to M).  All 3 tables contain the project name in column C.

When the macro is run, it starts in the MPL sheet, prompts the user for a new project name then adds it on a new row in alphabetical order.  This works well.

The next step is for the CAD sheet.  As I stated, there are 3 tables.  I am able to insert the new project, however it only inserts into 1 of the tables where the new name shows in column C.  This is where I am at a loss.  I believe I must find a way to put all values of column C into some sort of array, do a count then add a row on each instance.

Does this sound like a logical plan?  I have searched endlessly for a way to do this and can't seem to gain any ground.  The "iRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(strNewProject, Range("C:C")) + 1" method seems to suffice on a single table.

Any pointers in the right direction are appreciated.

```
Option Explicit 'forces declaration of variables

'PROCEDURES-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub Add_Project()

'---Procedure description/Notes---------------------------------------------------------------
'Macro Overview:
    'This procedure is used to add new projects to the Planner
    'Once the macro is started, the user will be prompted for a new
    'project name.  The new name(assuming it does not already exist) will
    'be added to the 'MPL' and 'CAD' tabs.  
'Assumptions
    'This procedure assumes the list of projects are contained in
    'column B.  If you get an error, update the column #s below.

'---Variable Declarations---------------------------------------------------------------------
Dim strNewProject As String
Dim iRow As Long

'---Code--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'so you don't have to see the screen flicker as the code switches sheets, cells, etc.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Go to the Master Project List sheet
Sheets("MPL").Select

'Input Box prompting user for Project Name
strNewProject = InputBox("Enter Project Name")
If Len(strNewProject) = 0 Then Exit Sub 'Pressed cancel

'Checks if the project already exists, displays message if true
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns("B"), strNewProject) > 0 Then
   MsgBox "Project already exists"
    Exit Sub
End If

'Add the new  value to the existing list, alphabetically
iRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(strNewProject, Columns("B")) + 1
Intersect(Range("tMPL"), Rows(iRow)).Insert _ ' tMPL is an Excel table
XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown, CopyOrigin:=Excel.XlInsertFormatOrigin.xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Cells(iRow, "B").Value = strNewProject

'Go to the CAD sheet
Sheets("CAD").Select

'****This is where things do not work the way that I need them to*****
'Add the new  value to the existing list, alphabetically
iRow = WorksheetFunction.Match(strNewProject, Range("C:C")) + 1
Rows(iRow).EntireRow.Insert
Cells(iRow, "C").Value = strNewProject

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your tables in sheet 'CAD' are separated by a blank row and the tables themselves are contiguous on column C (no blanks from start to end for the individual tables) then maybe something like this could work for you.  It inserts a new line as the first line in the table, puts in the project name, and then sorts the table by the project name.  Note that the tables on sheet 'CAD' are assumed to use a header row and that the header in column C for each table is "Project Name", adjust as necessary:

```
Sub tgr()

    Const strHeader As String = "Project Name"

    Dim wsMPL As Worksheet
    Dim wsCAD As Worksheet
    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim strFirst As String
    Dim strNewProject As String

    Set wsMPL = Sheets("MPL")
    Set wsCAD = Sheets("CAD")

    strNewProject = InputBox("Enter New Project Name:", "New Project")
    If Len(strNewProject) = 0 Then Exit Sub 'Pressed cancel

    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wsMPL.Columns("B"), strNewProject) > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Project with name [" & strNewProject & "] already exists.", , "New Project Error"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Insert new line with project name and sort data
    Intersect(Range("tMPL"), wsMPL.Rows(2)).Insert
    wsMPL.Range("B2").Value = strNewProject
    Range("tMPL").Sort wsMPL.Range("B2"), xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess

    'Insert new line into each table on wsCAD with project name and sort data
    With wsCAD
        Set rngFound = .Columns("C").Find(strHeader, .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C"), xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
            strFirst = rngFound.Address
            Do
                rngFound.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown
                rngFound.Offset(1).Value = strNewProject
                rngFound.CurrentRegion.Sort rngFound, xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
                Set rngFound = .Columns("C").Find("Project Name", rngFound, xlValues, xlWhole)
            Loop While rngFound.Address <> strFirst
        End If
    End With

    Set wsMPL = Nothing
    Set wsCAD = Nothing
    Set rngFound = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks tigeravatar!  I modified the first portion of the code you provided to adapt to the MPL sheet.  It works perfectly!  I am going to test the 2nd half a bit more and will keep you posted on the status.  One thing I realized that I didn't disclose is that the 3 tables in the CAD sheet all reference the table in MPL (i.e. =B5, =B6, etc.).  The sort function on CAD will force the associated columns to not match the project.  I am going to experiment a bit with a VLOOKUP function to see if that will solve it.  Thanks again!  Will reply with the final outcome.

Comment: After a few edits within my CAD sheet, your code executed perfectly.  Thank you again for the assistance.  I will study this code in more detail to improve my VBA skills day by day.  Hopefully this will allow me to keep progressing on the code development that I have planned.  Much appreciated!!